# how to define return class with wildcard type parameter in Java spring Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi

I have a endpoint that has a return type `Summary<Top, ? extends Header>` I know that swagger cannot autodetect the type here, but is there a way for me to manually define what are the possible return types here? There arent many so i could manually tell what this endpoint returns.

I know i should use @ApiResponse where i define @Schema but i have not found a good example on how should i define the Schema for this generic class( java record).

Putting @Schema inside Summary is not an option since this object is returned by many endpoints with many different Top and Header combos. Most of the time they are know, but 3 endpoints can return more than 1 type of header based on some parameters, thats why the wildcard usage.